# Make button appear and then disappear after a few seconds in Android

Tags: android

I have a few Buttons that I want to appear randomly and then disappear after a few seconds. I would also like them to be clickable when they are visible if that changes anything.

Here's what I have:

```
public void fight() throws InterruptedException
{
    Random g = new Random();
    int move;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        move = g.nextInt(8);
        buttons[move].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttons[move].setClickable(true);

        try{ Thread.sleep(5000); }catch(InterruptedException e){ }

        buttons[move].setVisibility(View.GONE);
        buttons[move].setClickable(false);
    }

}
```

When I try that though, the whole thing just freezes for 20 seconds (presumably 5 seconds for each time through the loop and nothing happens. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: It's freezing because you are sleeping the UI thread. Run a timer in a background thread, and in the callback, hide the button. See the in-built Timer class (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

Comment: Yes. I'd definitely implement it using a `Timer` with its tasks or a `Handler` with delayed `Runnables`.

Comment: I tried using a Timer, but I got this error message: CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: I got it working, it's pretty ugly though. For whatever reason, I'm not allowed to answer my own question for a few hours, so I'll try and remember to put something up tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void fight() throws InterruptedException
{
    Random g = new Random();
    int move;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() {
            while(makeACondition) {
            move = g.nextInt(8);
            buttons[move].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttons[move].setClickable(true);

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 5000 == 0) {

                buttons[move].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                buttons[move].setClickable(false);
            }
          } 
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: That just made them all show up immediately. Also, it's `System.currentTimeMillis()` just as an edit.

Comment: This needs to be completely redesigned.  Sorry I don't have time for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Handler mMessageHandler = new Handler();
Random g = new Random();
int move;

private Runnable mUpdaterRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // hide current button
        buttons[move].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        // set next button
        move = g.nextInt(8);
        // show next button
        buttons[move].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // repeat after 5 seconds
        mMessageHandler.postDelayed(mUpdaterRunnable, 5000);
    }
};
```

To start, use `move = g.nextInt(8);` (to avoid the null) and `mMessageHandler.post(mUpdaterRunnable);`.

To stop, `mMessageHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdaterRunnable);`.

You could also achieve this using `Timer` with `TimerTask`s, as xbonez said.

Comment: In `mMessageHandler.postDelayed(mUpdaterRunnable,5000);` `mUpdaterRunnable` is giving me a `The local variable mUpdaterRunnable may not have been initialized` error. Any idea?

Comment: Impossible. If you defined `mUpdaterRunnable` globally in your class definition, it would be already initialized. You're doing something wrong on your side.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this way ?

```
private int move;
public void fight() throws InterruptedException
{
    final Random g = new Random();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() {
            while(makeACondition) {
            move = g.nextInt(8);

            toggleButtonState(buttons[move]);
          } 
       }
   });
}

private void toggleButtonState(final Button button)
{
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(button.isEnabled())
                button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else 
                button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }, 5000);

}
```